# Dynamic settings in retrofit2 when it created with Dagger2

Tags: android, retrofit2, dagger-2

I create `dagger2` module for `retrofit2`

```
@Module
public class NetworkModule {

    private Context context;

    public NetworkModule(Application app) {
        this.context = app;
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    Context providesContext() {
        return context;
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    OkHttpClient providesOkHttpClient(Utils utils) {
        User user = utils.getSettings();
        return new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(Long.valueOf(user.getTimeOut()), TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(Long.valueOf(user.getTimeOut()), TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(Long.valueOf(user.getTimeOut()), TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build();
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    Retrofit providesRetrofit(OkHttpClient okHttpClient, Utils utils) {
        User user = utils.getSettings();
        String host = user.getHost();
        if (!host.endsWith("/")) host += "/";
        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(host)
                .addConverterFactory(JacksonConverterFactory.create())
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .client(okHttpClient).build();
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    RestApiFactory providesRestApiFactory(Retrofit retrofit) {
        return new RestApiFactory(retrofit);
    }
}
```

I have settings activity where user can change baseUrl, timeOut. If I create

```
providesRetrofit 
providesRestApiFactory
providesOkHttpClient
```

like `@Singleton` - after change settings it not change. If I remove `@Singleton` annotation - all work. My questions - how can I update dagger `@Singleton` when user change data?

Comment: Try to call Builder.build again. It maybe require a big cost I dont know but it can be work.

Answer (score 0):

Place NetworkModule in separate component(likely Subcomponent of your main Component) and recreate it when user changes baseUrl, timeout etc.

You can do that by creating interface annotated with `@Subcomponent` and adding your network module there. You can instantiate this Subcomponent by invoking method from your main component that you also need to add.

Detailed tutorial

https://google.github.io/dagger/subcomponents.html